# How to ignore some files when running type checking some files using tsc

Tags: typescript

I would like to ignore some files when type checking some files using tsc and cannot figure out how this is done in TypeScript.
Tools like eslint or flow allow special comments in the source files that allow to control the compiler.

Comment: // @ts-nocheck
this disables checks for the file

Answer (score 17):

Adding `// @ts-nocheck` at the top of the file will ignore the entire file.

In individual files, you can ignore specific lines by adding `// @ts-ignore` on the preceding line.

Use of `// @ts-expect-error` `// @ts-ignore` `// @ts-nocheck` `// @ts-check` is however not recommended since they suppress errors and therefore should be used sparingly. It is common practice in many cases to use eslint plugins to disable these to start with to avoid unforeseen errors. More on that [here](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/ban-ts-comment/)

and exclude files/folders using glob patterns in your `tsconfig.json` as below as long long as they aren't imported in other files such as in the case of independent unit test files and the like

```
{
    "exclude": [
        "**/*.spec.ts"
    ]
}
```

more about that, [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html)

Comment: Unfortunately @ts-nocheck only seems to work with .js files but not with .ts files.

Comment: Unfortunately also the exclude option is not working because tsc processes the excluded files anyway if imported.

Comment: Bummer! I've edited the answer to reflect that info.

Comment: @doberkofler Did you find an answer for this? How do we exclude or ignore the files which have been imported as well. For example, I want to ignore a config.json file which has been imported in a .ts file.

Comment: @doberkofler I wonder if that changed, because when I add `@ts-nocheck` at the top of a `.ts` file, in IDE the errors go away.